# For what are responsible weights?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning

I'm reading the google ML crash course and have one question.
What is a weight? (I understand that this is a slope in a plot, but it doesn't fit into my understanding)

I also don't understand an impact of weight on the model prediction (for example, in this [playground](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/crash-course/reducing-loss/playground-exercise))

Many thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every layer in a model is a huge mathematical function with many "unknown" variables.

When you build a model, you build a monster function (with thousands or millions of unknown variables) that gives an output from an input.

Something like this:

```
output_tensor = huge_function(your_input_tensor,var1,var2,var3,var4.......,var10000000)
```

These variables are the weights. At the beginning, they receive random values, and obviously your function gives you terrible results.

As you train, you adjust the values of these variables so that your results improve.

Weights are such variables, the ones in the model that you are going to adjust so that your huge function brings you good results.

**Weights x Biases**

Depending on what you are reading, or what program you're using, they will be called weights. According to what I wrote above, both fit the description.

But usually:

- Weights - Multiply the inputs
- Biases - Are added to the multiplied outputs

So, the usual layers (with some important differences, of course), perform operations like:

```
output_matrix = input_matrix x weights + biases
```

Nothing prevents you from creating custom operations, though, where your variables/weights neither multiply nor add.